# How to break closures in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to break a closure easily in JavaScript? The closest I have gotten is this:

```
var src = 3;
function foo () {
    return function () {
        return src; }
    }
function bar (func) {
    var src = 9;
    return eval('('+func.toString()+')')(); // This line
}
alert(bar(foo()));
```

This prints '9', instead of '3', as a closure would dictate. However, this approach seems kind of ugly to me, are there any better ways?

Comment: Why ever would you need to do this? O_o

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What you're describing just seems to be a completely wrong kind of thing to want to do.

Comment: Gosh, you're literally pounding the best part of JavaScript with its worst part.... I'm crying right now ;_; -1

Comment: Sorry, don't understand the downvotes. I think this is a great question. You need to know the bad and good things about a lauguage. +1

Comment: @James There's no more hope here, just look at the code formatting, he uses eval, he wants to break closures... well maybe there is one tiny little bit of hope left, still WIP but it might help here: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/

Comment: @James: I agree. There's a reason that the book "JavaScript: The good parts" has a chapter called "The bad parts" (and one called "The awful parts"). Trying to break a language or do something stupid is quite educating. Or put another way: "How much can you possibly know about yourself if you've never been in a fight?"

Comment: I'm not saying this is a good way to do it. I'm asking for a better way. This was just an example of the only way I know how to work with it.

Comment: You used to be able to, in Firefox, by using eval( s, o )... see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=442333  I wonder if there is still a way (without poking around in memory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others said this doesn't seem to be the right thing to do. You should explain why you want this and what you want to achieve.

Anyway, one possible approach could be to access properties of an object inside your function. Example:

```
var src = 3;

function foo (context) {
    context = context || window; // Fall back to the global namespace as default context

    return function () {
        return context.src; 
    }
}

function bar (func) {
    var context = {src: 9};
    return func(context);
}

alert(bar(foo));
```

Comment: I'd guess this means "Don't use closures.", and to use Objects instead. Which may be what I have to do. I think I could try to pass an arguments function then use a with statement, as ugly as that would be.

Comment: It doesn't mean "Don't use closures". Closures are great. It just seems like you've not yet understood what they are for, if the code in your question is an attempt to solve a real problem.

Comment: I know what closure is, but I need to compile code from a file, and use it somewhere else, while having access to private variables.

Comment: @Not a Name: It would be much easier to suggest a better way, if you expanded more on your actual problem than your perceived solution.

Answer (score 9):

Your code is not breaking the closure, you're just taking the code the makes up a function and evaluating it in a different context (where the identifier `src` has a different value). It has nothing at all to do with the closure that you've created over the original `src`.

It is impossible to inspect data that has been captured in a closure. In a sense, such data are even more "private" than private members in Java, C++, C# etc where you can always use reflection or pointer magic to access them anyway.

Answer (score 3):

This could be useful if you are trying to create multiple similar methods in a loop.  For example, if you're creating a click handler in a loop that relies on a loop variable to do something a little different in each handler.  (I've removed the "eval" because it is unnecessary, and should generally never be used).

```
// Assign initial value
var src = 3;

// This is the regular js closure.  Variables are saved by reference.  So, changing the later will
// change the internal value.
var byref = function() {
  return src;
}

// To "break" the closure or freeze the external value the external function is create and executed
// immidiatly.  It is used like a constructor function which freezes the value of "src".
var byval = function(s) {
  return function() { return s };
}(src);

src = 9;

alert("byref: " + byref()); // output: 9
alert("byval: " + byval()); // output: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access a variable in a wider scope, just don't reuse the variable name in a narrower scope.

That's how it is supposed to work. Work with it instead of trying to fight it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code see if you can understand , closures defined within a loop .

```
 var clicked  = false;
 for(var i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
  (function(index){
   if(clicked) return false;
   $(temp[index]).on('click',function(){
     if($(temp[index]).text()=="" && !$(".cell1").val()){
       $(this).text(player1Val);
       $(".cell1").val(true);
       console.log("first player clicked ");
       clicked = true;
       $(this).off();
       for(var j=0;j<temp.length;j++){
          $(temp[j]).off('click');
       }
       return false;
    }
    else return false;
   });
 })(i);
}
```